# How do I handle an "incomplete multibyte character" error from Postgres using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

I'm writing a Ruby program to fetch some code from the net and sometimes it had this error:

```
Error incomplete multibyte character.
```

I'm trying to `escape()` the string using pg.

How can I handle this error? How can I convert the string to a valid UTF8 string?

Comment: Why don't you help us out by showing some sample code?

Comment: What does this have to do with PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

To convert between encodings, try ruby's Iconv class. It's in the standard library.

Comment: Note that iconv was deprecated in Ruby 1.9; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148762/iconv-deprecation-warning-with-ruby-1-9-3

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming in this discussion as I had the same issue.
Some tried something strange with my application and I received the following exception email report:

> PG::Error occurred in slides#show:
>
> incomplete multibyte character
>
> activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:472:in `escape_string'
>
> ---
>
> ### Request:
>
> - URL : http://www.roxcom.lu/slides/Vintage%20Gigolos++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Result:+%ed%e5+%ed%e0%f8%eb%ee%f1%fc+%f4%ee%f0%ec%fb+%e4%eb%ff+%ee%f2%ef%f0%e0%e2%ea%e8;
> - IP address: 91.200.14.57
> - Parameters: {"controller"=>"slides", "action"=>"show", "title"=>"Vintage Gigolos++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Result:+\xED\xE5+\xED\xE0\xF8\xEB\xEE\xF1\xFC+\xF4\xEE\xF0\xEC\xFB+\xE4\xEB\xFF+\xEE\xF2\xEF\xF0\xE0\xE2\xEA\xE8;"}
> - Rails root: /var/www/apps/roxcom.lu/releases/20130116132800
>
> ---
>
> ### Session:
>
> - session id: nil
> - data: {}

So how to handle this case ?

Comment: Sorry... I wrote it as Answer but wasn't an answer... shame on me. :(